# Scrapy - Pass session on to requests

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, session-cookies

Got this code:

```py
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from retrieve_image import retrieve_image

class LoginSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'loginspider'
    login_page = 'http://145.100.108.148/login5/login.php'
    start_urls = ['http://145.100.108.148/login5/index.php']
    username = 'test@hotmail.com'
    password = 'test'

    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.start_requests)

    def start_requests(self):
        print ("\n start_request is here \n")
        yield Request(
        url = self.login_page,
        callback = self.login,
        cookies={'PHPSESSID': 'something'},
        dont_filter = True
        )

    def login(self, response):
        captcha = execute.split('\n')[0]
        print(captcha)
        print ("\n Login is here! \n")
        retrieve_image(response, self.login_page)
```

On this page there is a captcha image which is tied to a session.

I am trying to download the CAPTCHA image from the url via retrieve_image.py. I should do this with using the same session, but when running the scraper, it downloads an empty image, meaning it is not the same session. I thought the session would be equal because the PHPSESSID is equal.

Here is retrieve_image.py:

```py
import bs4
import lxml
import requests
import io
import urllib2

def retrieve_image(page, server):
    for i in range(1):
        cookies = dict(PHPSESSID='something')

        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.body, "lxml")
        samples = soup.find(id="captcha", src=True)['src']
        another = soup.find('div', {'class:', 'test'})

        #print(page.body)
        #print("Another text -> " + another.text)

        image_url = str(server + samples)
        print(image_url)
        print('\n HERE IS I \n')
        print(requests.get(image_url, cookies=cookies))
        print('\n')
        img_data = requests.get(image_url, cookies=cookies).content

        # print("doe ff image data\n" +img_data)
        myString = '_num' + str(i) + '.png'

        print(another.text + myString)
        with open(another.text + myString, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
```

In settings.py

```py
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you downloading captcha image with an external script?

Just use same Scrapy's Request method to download image.

```
def login(self, response):

    #If captcha exists
    if response.css("#captcha").extract_first() is not None:
        captchaImageLink = response.css("#captcha::attr(src)").extract_first()

        yield Request(captchaImageLink, callback = self.saveCaptchaImage)


def saveCaptchaImage(self, response):

    output = open("captchaImageFile.jpg","wb")
    output.write(response.body)
    output.close()
```

Comment: I received error: 'Missing scheme in request url', so I did:
    url = 'http://145.100.108.148'

captchaImageLink to:             captchaImageLink = self.url + response.css(....

Now it works, if you change your code I can mark it as solution!

Comment: @ErikTol `Missing scheme in request url` means you are missing `https` or `http` at beginning of your URL.

Comment: Perhaps cause its using IP instead of DNS. Anyway, it works. Only the response object changed, now I cannot continue because I need to work in the same session.

Comment: @ErikTol after `saveCaptchaImage` and solving captcha, you can again visit that previous URL which you want to access